# TreeNode when Selected Change Foreground/Background Color

Tags: vb.net, winforms, treeview

Essentially I'm trying to find a way to click on an area of a TreeView and have that area highlighted.  Them problem always seems to be unhighlighting the area after another node is selected.  I'm toyed and searched over and over again.. and well.. finally I'm asking b/c I can't get it work properly.  I'd show my code but not it's just a nasty mess of consolidated code. Does anyone have a good working example?

to clarify just the basics:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                  ByVal e As TreeViewEventArgs) _
                                  Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect           
  'e.Node.BackColor = Color.Yellow 
End Sub
```

I've tried to use numerous methods to set and deselect by looping through the collection. It never seems to work!

Comment: Note sure I understand what "click on an area" means.  Are you trying to just click on a node and draw a custom highlight color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the DrawMode for the TreeView control to `OwnerDrawText` and use this drawing code:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_DrawNode(ByVal sender As Object, _
                               ByVal e As DrawTreeNodeEventArgs) _
                               Handles TreeView1.DrawNode
  If (e.State And TreeNodeStates.Selected) <> 0 Then
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, e.Bounds)
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, e.Node.NodeFont, e.Bounds, _
                          Color.Black, Color.Empty, _
                          TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter)
  Else
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds)
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, e.Node.NodeFont, e.Bounds, _
                          SystemColors.WindowText, Color.Empty, _
                          TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter)
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: ingenious technique!  I wasn't aware of the property setting to bypass the way text is handled. Instead I was trying to loop through collections filled with 1000's of nodes to modify the color.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Step one-in the form, place one  textbox, one label and three horizontall scrollbars
step2-the next step is to set the properties of each controls.

1. label1-caption-background
2. text1-text-(leave it blank)
3. hscroll1-max-255
4. hscroll2-max-255
5. hscroll3-max-255

(given above are the control,property and settings)
  step3-this is the final step.that is to write the code.it is very simple.

```
Private Sub HScroll1_Change()(note:end of line1)
  Text1.BackColor = RGB(HScroll1.Value, HScroll2.Value, HScroll3.Value)(note:end of line2)
End Sub


Private Sub HScroll2_Change()(note:end of line1)
  Text1.BackColor = RGB(HScroll1.Value, HScroll2.Value, HScroll3.Value)(note:end of line2)
End Sub

Private Sub HScroll3_Change()(note:end of line1)
  Text1.BackColor = RGB(HScroll1.Value, HScroll2.Value, HScroll3.Value)(note:end of line2)
End Sub
```

Comment: this code works only for changing background color.i think u didn't understand the code.fine,i'll write it again.